# Why can't I retrieve user data from Djoser user endpoint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

So I'm testing my djoser url endpoints from djoser almost every endpoints worked but I cant get the user from `/users/me/`, I'm using JWT and and here's my postman headers
[image]

I got the JWT from the login process but it still returns an error as displayed in the screenshot
and my server also says

```
Forbidden: /auth/users/me/
[04/Jul/2021 02:10:28] "GET /auth/users/me/ HTTP/1.1" 403 58
```

what's causing this error?

P.S tell me if you need more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your Authorization field. You're using `JWT`, but acutally you should `Bearer`.

Change your authorization field to `Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`. Naturally, change `ACCESS_TOKEN` for a valid access token.

Let us know if it has solved your problem.

Comment: That's not the course of the problem. It happened to me too.